# Can concurrent processes be run in a single model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

In model builder (for Arc GIS 10) is it possible to run two or more geoprocessing operations concurrently?

For example I have to run repair geometry on 2 files and then merge them. Currently it repairs topo of file A and then file B and then merges them. Each file takes about 30h to repair. Can I get it to concurrently repair A & B, wait for both to be complete and then merge them.

At the moment I have to open two instances of arc catalog and run the repair tool on a file in each and once complete do a merge which means that I have to come in to office to check when both are complete...on a quad core, each repair process only uses 1 core at a time.

The above example is simple but if multi-threading is possible where multiple operations are run concurrently (if they don't depend on each other) and wait for the depended files to be complete before the next process is run.

Thanks,

Comment: No, but you may be interested in this Geoprocessing Blog post about using multiprocessing in Python: http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/geoprocessing/archive/2011/08/29/Multiprocessing.aspx

Comment: Thanks blah238. It would be really great if we could do this and get arcgis to use multiple cores for operations. If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it for you to get status points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you may be interested in [this Geoprocessing Blog](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/geoprocessing/archive/2011/08/29/Multiprocessing.aspx) post about using multiprocessing in Python.

You could create a Python [script tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001500000006000000.htm) that handles the multiprocessing part and call that in ModelBuilder, however I think that it needs to run "out of process" for multiprocessing to work correctly.

Here's an example of a multiprocessing script tool: [Find Duplicates in Big Data](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=2803AD4F-1422-2418-34AD-8311C064AFA2)

Comment: thanks for this link...I have been looking at it and it seems to simply split the data into sections based on rows. I am trying to do an interesect and for that the data (say for aspect, slope and vegetation) needs to be split into zones which are geographically the same...any idea on how to do this?